swagger и python
Имеется swagger-контракт в формате yaml для подключения к WEB. как я его могу использовать в python для подключения к API? Никакой документации я не мог найти. Только на создание swagger. Как его использовать не пойму. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Видимо что-то такое вам нужно: https://github.com/openapi-generators/openapi-python-client. Но это для OpenAPI 3.0, для более старого что-то другое нужно искать. Поисковой запрос - "openapi autogenerate python client"
